# Simulating a divide area random variable

Tags: simulation

Suppose that we have a random variable with pdf like
$f = \left\{
\begin{array}{ c l }
x+1,    x\in [-1,0] \\
-x+1,   x\in (0,1]
\end{array}
\right.$ and we have to simulate it.

It's pdf is 
$F(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ c l }
x^2/2+x+0.5,    x\in [-1,0] \\
-x^2/2+x+0.5,   x\in (0,1]
\end{array}
\right.$

two methods to simulate this can be found here http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~hwan/IE680/Lectures/Chap08Slides.pdf page 12.

My question is if we can simulate problems like that by fist simulate a random U(0,1) and

**if it is small**er than the probability  $P(x\in [-1,0])=1/2$ simulate from the first part with inverse transformation $\sqrt{2U}-1$ but for a $U\sim Unif(0,1/2=P(x\in [-1,0]))$

**and if it is bigger**  simulate  with inverse transformation $1-\sqrt{(2(1-U))}$ *using* a $U\sim Unif(1/2,1)$.

When I make the histogram it seems to working, but is it correct?

```
[code]rand=function(){
if(runif(1,0,1)<=1/2){x=sqrt(2*runif(1,0,1/2))-1}else{
x=1-sqrt(2-2*runif(1,1/2,1))
}
return(x)
}


pri=NULL


for(i in 1:10000)
{
pri=c(pri,rand())
}


hist(pri,prob=T)[/code]
```

Comment: Can you show us your code for making a histogram?

Comment: I edit my first post. Thanks.

Comment: Though Kolmogorov used small letters to denote random variables in [his book](https://www.york.ac.uk/depts/maths/histstat/kolmogorov_foundations.pdf), I suggest using capital letters for theoretical stuff like events $E$ and random variables $X,U$, and small letters for observations like an instance $x$ of $X$ and the sample mean $\bar{x}_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code generates the correct results, but as you can see from the calculations below, it's hard to understand.  I suggest sticking with the linked lecture notes and use `runif(1,0,1)`, which represents $\mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$.

The composition algorithm in the linked notes:

> 1. Generate two independent $U_1, U_2 \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$
> 2. - If $U_1 < 1/2$,  return $X = \sqrt{U_2}-1$
>    - Otherwise, return $X = 1 - \sqrt{1-U_2}$

The composition algorithm in the question body contains a rescaled version of $U_2$.

> 1. Generate $U_1 \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$
> 2. - $U_1 < 1/2$,  return $X = \sqrt{2U}-1$ for $U\sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,1/2)$
>        In fact, $2U \stackrel{(d)}{=} U_2$.
>    - Otherwise, return $X = 1 - \sqrt{2-2U}$ for $U\sim \mathrm{Unif}(1/2,1)$
>        In fact, $2U \sim \mathrm{Unif}(1,2)$, so $2-2U \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$ and $2-2U \stackrel{(d)}{=} 1-U_2$.

---

These figures illustrates the how the code works.

[image: histogram by OP's algo]

If we increase the sample size from 10k to 50k, the histogram looks more similar to the triangular distribution on $[-1,1]$.

[image]

We increasing the class number from 20 to 50 in order to take a closer look of the data.

[image]

---

My code

```
rand=function(){
if(runif(1,0,1)<=1/2){x=sqrt(2*runif(1,0,1/2))-1}else{
x=1-sqrt(2-2*runif(1,1/2,1))
}
return(x)
}

pri=NULL
for(i in 1:50000)
{
pri=c(pri,rand())
}

hist(pri,breaks=50,prob=T)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to find a way to prove that we can work like this (like the one I posted) in all the similar problems, but I couldn't prove something that will work on every case. Anyway thanks again.